# Udev not create the new symlink

Tags: udev, symbolic-link

I would like to assign a static symlink to my usb device.

`lsusb` output:

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0461:4d81 Primax Electronics, Ltd Dell N889 Optical Mouse
```

Then I create a udev rules file under `/etc/udev/rules.d` with the filename `99-myusb.rules` (I use `chmod 777` to avoid file permission issue).

```
KERNEL=="ttyUSB*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0461", ATTRS{idProduct}=="4d81", SYMLINK+="/dev/myusb"
```

However, I reboot or run `udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger`.

The symlink isn't been created when I try `ls /dev`.

Can you help me solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Change your udev-rule

```
KERNEL=="mouse0",  SUBSYSTEM=="input", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0461", ATTRS{idProduct}=="4d81", SYMLINK+="myusb"
```

But I would create your symlink in /dev/input/

```
SYMLINK+="input/myusb"
```

You can find correct value with

```
udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/input/mouse0 --attribute-walk
```

this is all for the 1. Usb-mouse

```
readlink -f /dev/input/myusb 
/dev/input/mouse0
```

Comment: May i know how to check whether my system has load the certain rules file? Is the any command to check it?

Comment: `udevadm test --action=add /sys/class/input/mouse0`

Answer (score 0):

I get the parameters for the rules from the same info section to identify two Raspberry's Pico with the next rules in file:

`SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", KERNELS=="1-1", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2e8a", SYMLINK+="device1"`
`SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", KERNELS=="1-2", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2e8a", SYMLINK+="device2"`

`udevadm info --name=/dev/ttyACM0 --attribute-walk`

```
looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/tty/ttyACM0':
 KERNEL=="ttyACM0"
 SUBSYSTEM=="tty"
 DRIVER==""
```

```
looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0':
 KERNELS=="1-2:1.0"
 SUBSYSTEMS=="USB"
 DRIVERS=="cdc_acm"
 ...
```

```
looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2':
 KERNELS=="1-2"
 SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
 DRIVERS=="usb"
 ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="ef"
 ATTRS{idProduct}=="00c0"
 ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 2"
 ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="500mA"
 ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
 ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
 ATTRS{serial}=="B73860E637757213"
 .......
 ATTRS{product}=="RaspberryPi Pico"
 ATTRS{idVendor}=="2e8a"
 ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
```

`udevadm control --reload`

`udevadm trigger`

...unplug and plug again...and voila...

Comment: Please use code formatting for commands and screen output.